# VM running Wireshark using USB wireless card for network is not displaying data correctly

Tags: virtualbox, backtrack

I have BT running in a VM on windows 7. I just setup my Alfa wireless card with the VM. I'm able to connect to my wireless network correctly but having issues with wireshark data. When i go to capture data i select start on USBMon1, but all the data i see is for protocol USB. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First... stop virtualizing.  There is a reason the BT framework comes on a bootable ISO.

Second... just because you can select your wifi card as a virtual network adapter... does not mean it will work properly.  For BT/almost any good wifi-tools out there, you must be able to configure your wifi adapter into some form of promiscuous mode; meaning it will capture and report all traffic... and not just the packets that are destined for that machine.

Comment: Well i purchased the Alfa AWUS036H for this reason. So i guess it's just not possible being in a VM? Doesn't entirely make sense I've heard in the past people saying BT runs great virtualized.

Comment: Don't attach the network adapter as a virtual network adapter... attach it as a usb device... and let the BT have full control of it.